# omitted tests are not included in cypress test report (json)

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm using cypress with cucumber, also I have set the config to `"omitFiltered": false,`

Also I am using the following versions of cypress and the cucumber  preprocessor

```
"cypress": "^12.17.3",
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "18.0.2",
```

When executing the tests I can see the omitted tests are marked as Pending, but in the json report those tests are not available

Is there a way to get these tests to json report as skipped or any other status?

[image]